# Evaluating $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u\log u}$.

Tags: calculus

I know we use $u$-substitution for $\log u$ and then we find the derivative but after that i'm confused. This is because the question is already using $u$ as a variable. Any explanation would be appreciated.

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u\log u}$$

Comment: You can use a different variable name for the substitution, like $v$ (let $v = \log u$).

Comment: Compare $\frac{1}{\log(u)}\frac{1}{u}du$ with the integrand in the left-hand side of the formula for the change of variable: $\int f(g(u))g'(u)du=\int f(v)dv$, with $v=g(u)$. Take into account that $(\log(u))'=\frac{1}{u}$. The choice of taking $g(u)=\log(u)$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, such that $f(g(u))=\frac{1}{\log(u)}$ and $g'(u)du=\frac{1}{u}du$ becomes apparent.

Answer (score 5):

If $x=\log u$, then $dx/du=1/u$, so we have
$$\int\frac{du}{u\log u}=\int\frac{dx}{x}=\log|x|+C=\log|\log u|+C$$

Comment: That's assuning that the log here is the natural logarithm, "ln". If this problem is from an elementary calculus problem, then of course, it needs a small extra step

Comment: In pure mathematics, I believe that is what $\log$ means. If using a different base that ought to be specified.

Comment: Why was the absolute value on log x added?

Comment: @OGK Because we cannot take the log of a negative. The domain of the log function is only the positive real numbers.